# Phoenix template rendering slow with link and helper functions

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm finding rendering templates slow using the `link` function and generated path helper functions.

For example, I run `mix phoenix.gen.html Author authors name:string`

Inside `index.html.eex` there is

`<%= for author <- @authors do %>
   # ...
   <%= link "Show", to: author_path(@conn, :show, author) %>
<% end %>`

The response time is over 2 seconds for 1,500 author records. However, if I comment out the above `link` function with `author_path`, the response time is only 9 milliseconds. Database query time is the same (4ms) in either case.

I tried removing `link` and printing only `author_path(@conn, :show, author)` instead. This helps, but the response time is still over 500ms.

Thank you for any advice on how I can find the source of this slow performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to protocols not being consolidated in development prior to Elixir 1.2. You'll find if you run in prod, your renders will be lightening fast. If you jump on Elixir 1.2, protocols are always consolidated, even when in dev.

Comment: Correction: Elixir 1.2 will always consolidated protocols which should be out in a week or two. Elixir 1.1 always consolidate protocols only for production.